# Redirect to website using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, url, redirect, web

I just started learning PHP, and I wanted to make a redirection to a new site. I want it to be somewhat like the `location.href="http://example.com"` in Javascript, but I didn't find anything... Any ideas?

Comment: Here's an idea for you: [RTM: `header` is what you need](http://www.php.net/header)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: echo '<br><a href="http:// example.com">Go to website</a><br>';

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you have to set `header`. Check [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
header("Location:http://example.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
header("location: http://example.com");

exit();
```

`exit()` is must, else the codes after header will be executed.

Comment: `exit() is must`: just that it's not. So what if the remaining code is executed? It's not a must its just a precaution for lazy programmers. If the code was written well then a redirect would be made at the logical end of the code where there is no further processing left.

Comment: @Hanky, i think the termination of script execution & calling the destructors might be the enough reason for using the exit() after header()
:)

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP code you have to set header like below

```
header("Location:http://example.com");
exit();
```

Or you can set like this

```
<?php
   echo"<script>window.location='URL of your website'</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the HTML/HTTP redirection tag. Just paste the following

```
<?php
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />'
?>
```

Please escape the quotes and change the URL appropriately.

This should be the first line written to the browser or it may or may not work.

Repeat
Using Javascript

```
<?php
echo '<script type='text/javascript''>window.location.href='example.com'</script>
```

?>

Please escape the quotes appropriately